# Brush-less motor specs vs efficiency for multi-copters

Tags: brushless-motor

I am looking for some figures surrounding the specs of brushless motors and their relative efficiency (in power usage terms) for multi-copter use.

There are 4 basic specs for motors themselves:
 - Motor width (EG 28mm)
 - Motor height (EG 30mm)
 - "KV" - RPM per volt supplied (EG 800KV)
 - wattage (eg 300w)

This would then be a 28-30 800kv 300w motor.

What i am looking for is a chart containing:
 - Motor spec
 - pack voltage (eg 14.8v)
 - Amps drawn @ various % throttle (10% to 100% say)
 - static thrust from various propellers (11x5, 12x6 etc etc)

Does such information exist?
I know its a BIT subjective as prop and motor designs vary slightly, but a baseline would be a start.

Comment: To say that it's a bit subjective to prop choice would be an understatement...

Comment: exactly, so it would have to be based on the same prop design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [eCalc Multicopter Calculator](http://www.ecalc.ch/xcoptercalc.php?ecalc&lang=en). You select a set of motors, propellers and battery size and the program will output lots of data: Thrust, Motor efficiency at hover, Current and Voltage at hover, Motor efficiency at maximum power, Current and Voltage at maximum power, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The programm you are searching for is http://www.drivecalc.de/

They have all the common motors with lot of data... some "special" motors you won't find there